# Firebase (Swift) runTransactionBlock: permission denied

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

May I ask what runTransactionBlock is doing behind the hood? When I run a simple setValue with the exact same rules it works, but not with runTransactionBlock. **I suspect that behind the hood runTransactionBlock writes to paths outside of just the path I stated, which is causing my security rules to deny permission.** Hence, I have to write a global `".write": "auth != null"` and avoid doing stuff such as my wildcard `".validate": false`.

My security rules are mapped out this way:

```
{
  "rules": {
        // NOTE: I NEED THIS GLOBAL WRITE ALLOW FOR TRANSACTION TO WORK
        ".write": "auth != null",
    "real_db": {
    // USERS
    "users": {
      "$user": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        "$other": {
          // NOTE: I NEED TO COMMENT VALIDATE FOR OTHER FIELDS IN USER
          // ".validate": false
        },
        "pushToken": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".validate": "auth != null"
        },
        ...
```

My runTransactionBlock is run on the path `real_db/users/$uid` and I am changing the value of `pushToken`. When setValue is run on this same path and modifying `pushToken` it works.